# PHP Page redirection with javascript

Tags: php, redirect

a small problem ! I have a login form in a PHP file. I have used javascript validation for the form. On a login success scenario i am redirecting the user to their home page.

I have used `header("Location:index.php")`.

I know that the header must be before any output must be sent to the browser. My question is there any walk around to do this redirection?

Comment: try to use output buffering for `header()` to function even header is already sent..

Comment: Use header logically, code header related function in the beginning. I do not find a reason to use then after any output sent. Use mvc pattern.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use

```
<script>
    window.location = 'http://www.example.com/newlocation';
</script>
```

to redirect after the headers are sent.

Comment: I tried this... but now the javascript validation doesn't take place?

Comment: Well... then i must use only server side validation huh? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

If you using javascript Use this

```
window.location.href = "index.php";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are ready to use the JavaScript you can use any one of the following method.

```
1.window.location.assign('http://www.example.com');
2.window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
3.window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using `header()` to redirect, you can use meta refresh method, or JS `window.location` method.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add a quick note to the previous answers.
if you want to use JavaScript for redirection generating the script
form the server-side is more secure.

```
<?php
$script = "<script>
window.location = 'http://www.example.com/newlocation';</script>";
echo $script;
?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why is it more secure?